# Extension fully installed, but maintenance flag not removed

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, install, installation, maintenance

I've written a new upgrade to an extension and it works just fine on my dev install.

When I package it, there are no problems.

**When I try to install it from connect manager I never see the console**,but the screen does scroll down to the console area.

If I refresh the connect manager my extension is listed.

All files are properly installed and the DB tables properly updated.

**The Maintenance flag is not removed**

After deleting the flag file, the extension functions perfectly.

this is all repeatable across multiple installation on different servers, using both CE 1.8 and 1.9.

What might be causing the flag being left and the console not working, and how can I fix it.  Even after several hours consulting google, I'm at a loss.  This is the only thing I know of preventing the release of this extension.

If I need to show any code, please ask for it.  At this point, I don't even know what files might be causing the problem.

first request, the upgrade code from file mysql4-upgrade-0.1.3-0.1.4.php :

```
    <?php

$installer = $this;
//no database changes for this upgrade
```

my version 0.1.3 installs just fine, my version 0.1.4 doesn't.

Comment: Can you place the installer or the update here?

Comment: added in an edit to the main question, the other installers are a bit long.  Since it worked up to the previous installer I thought they're probably not needed.  If you know better, please tell me and I'll add it.

Comment: How did you packed your extension?

Comment: Using the process in Magento, Just like outlined in "How to package Magento Extensions" on the Magento website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this `$installer->endSetup();`
at the bottom of your installer script.

Comment: I'll try, but I never had a startSetup();.  Also, 0.1.3 uses the exact same script, just with a different file name.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you have an update script if it does not do anything.

Comment: isn't it needed to move the version number up, so it matches the version in your xml?  If i don't move the version number, connect complains when I try to upload it, and I'm not sure if it installs the updated files if there's no installer to trigger the process.  Am I wrong?  That's always a possibility.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. If there is nothing to do in the installer, remove it.

Comment: Ok.  I can't test it at the moment but I'll post when I have.  

So how does magento know there are changes if there is no installer for the version?

Comment: You change the version in your extension config.xml.